# How to randomly set property value

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core, I need to set a property to a random string, but the random string will be generated from another property. The properties are

```
public class State
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Capital {get;set;}
    public string RandomCapital {get;set;}
}
```

Basically `Capital` has values state capitals as its values, and I need to set `RandomCapital` to random instances of `Capital` or random values, I am trying to do it using linq. In my controller all I have is a way to generate random values, but not set properties to random values. I know that if i put this in the controller it will generate x number of random values, but how do I set 3 random values in order to create a multiple choice quiz?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SetValues()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    var quiz = _context.States.OrderBy(c => random.Next()).Take(x);
    return View(quiz);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a quiz, you must want multiple capitals. So, this will do it

```cs
var rand = new Random();
var idx = rand.Next(0, _context.States.Count); 
var allStates = _context.States.ToArray(); 
var randState = allStates[idx]; // get random state

// now, you need 3 more states to fill random capital slots
var allButRandomStates = allStates.Where(s => s.Name != randState.Name).ToList();

// Get 3 additional random capitals via their states
var stateList = new List<State>(); 
while (stateList.Count < 3)
{
    idx = rand.Next(0, allButRandomStates.Count); 
    var st = allButRandomStates[idx]; // get random state
    allButRandomStates.Remove(st);  // remove from where you get it
    stateList.Add(st); // add to where you want it
}
// get capitals of your states
string[] randomCapitals = stateList.Select(s => s.Capital).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
var rand = new Random();
var idx = rand.Next(0, _context.States.Count); // get the random index of the item in the list
var randState = _context.States.ToArray()[idx]; // get random item

// if the capital is the capital of the random state
var capital = randState.Capital;
```

Comment: I 'can not apply indexing [] to expression of type DbSet<State>',and also would this even set the values for `RandomCapital`? I need `RandomCapital` to have values

Comment: @janzen I fixed it for you. For capital, you need to use capital list. Or is your capital is a capital of a given state?

Comment: well I did this and the view gives me an error that basically says, 'The view 'Indianapolis' was not found'. It works to pick random capitals but it returns the capital as a view, when I am trying to return a value to my `Capitals.cshtml` not create new views. Also when I use `var capital = randState.RandomCapital` which is what I would like to use as the random variable, I debug and get null for `RandomCapital` I am still trying though

Comment: @janzen if you have a different issue, lets say, "how to set a view", you should open a new  question. For the random capital, as I pointed out earlier, I am not clear what your input/output. My answer clearly shows **how to get a random value from the list**. This can be a state, a capital or anything else.

Comment: I know how to fetch a random value, my question is how to set a random value to the property `RandomCapital`. I dont need nor do I want to create new views, I want to set `RandomCapital` to a random value, then return that random value to the view

Comment: @janzen How is your random capital related to random state? I don't see any issue setting the capital. I only don't know where does it come from

Comment: sorry you're right, I have been unclear, basically I need to return random capitals because it is meant to be a multiple choice quiz. I have tried multiple things in my code and the whole time I should have rechecked to make sure I was being clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210766/discussion-between-janzen-and-t-s).

Comment: @janzen I added answer for capitals